# typeerror cannot read property 'currenttarget' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

When running the below mentioned code, I get the errormessage: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined".

Is it because I have currentTarget mentioned 2 places?

When only running 1 function "deleteFood" it doesnt give any errors.

```
<script>
let cB = document.getElementsByClassName("deleteFoodClass");
var anyBoxesUnchecked = [];
for (i = 0; i < cB.length; i++) {
    cB[i].addEventListener('click', checkBoxMarked);
}

function checkBoxMarked(arg) {
    var trueBoolean = "true";
    let elm = arg.currentTarget;
    let marked = elm.getAttribute('data-IngredientMarked');
    let id = elm.getAttribute('data-ingredientID');

    if(marked === true){
        anyBoxesUnchecked.push(id);      // ... and adding them to the array.
    } else
        anyBoxesUnchecked.splice(id);
}

function deleteFood(arg) {
    let el = arg.currentTarget;
    let id = el.getAttribute('data-ingredientID');

    console.log(id); // used for debugging

    var url = '/api/Ingredients/';
    var urlQuery = url.concat(id);
    for (i = 0; i < anyBoxesUnchecked.length; i++) {
    fetch(urlQuery,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            body: undefined,
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        })
        //.then(res => res.json())
        .catch(error => console.error('Error', error))
        .then(response => console.log('Sucess On Deletion', response));
    }
}

</script>
```

EDITED: It gives the following errors when trying to debug:
[Picture of debug message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoC3x.png)

SOLUTION: Found out that - for some reason, given that checkBoxMarked never was called - I tried replacing it with "function()", which solved the problem.

Comment: It looks like it should work. Can it be reproduced in a live example?

Comment: Yes, but it wont for some reason - @FrankModica I have attached the errormessage when trying to run the debugger, but I dont understand it. It is as if the two functions are never called, but that doesnt make any sense.

Comment: Are you setting a breakpoint in an IDE? What if you set a breakpoint in the browser dev tools?

Comment: 'i' is undefined here: for (i = 0; i < cB.length; i++) {
    cB[i].addEventListener('click', checkBoxMarked);
}

Not sure if it solves the problem, but worth a try.

Comment: @Torfiks That shouldn't be the problem. Tried defining it and it didn't help, but thanks.

Comment: @FrankModica Right now I am trying everything in the browsers debugger. It is as if the addEventListener doesn't work? If I just call cB.Lenght the console shows the correct number.

Comment: It's true though that `i` should be defined with `var i`, but that seems to be a separate issue

Comment: defining i was not the problem, though. The problem was, that "function()" needed to be added in the addEventListener. For some reason - which I don't know - it didn't call the "checkBoxMarked"-function. Replacing it with "function()" solved the problem.